# I can't call a method that's in the App_Code folder within the ashx file

Tags: asp.net, handler

The problem that I have (don't know what happened that cause it - it worked fine before):

I can't call a function in the `App_Code` folder from an `ashx` file (from a regular code behind C# file, it's working fine).

The class name is `SendMail` and the method name is `SendEmail`

The handler file:

[image]

Class set to 'compile'

[image]

The method

[image]

What can cause that?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Website project or an ASP.NET Web Application project? ("Websites" are created by going File > New Website, rather than File > New Project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two classes named `SendMail`, which is confusing both the compiler and you.  I highly recommend more meaningful naming of your components.

If your classes are in two different namespaces, you can reference the target class explicitly by using its entire namespace.  Something like:

```
YourNamespace.SendMail
```

Then you can call the method:

```
bool mailSent = YourNamespace.SendMail.SendEmail(firstName, lastName, ...
```

Comment: "You have two classes named SendMail" how can you tell that? Can you give an example according to my solution

Comment: @slash1z: I can tell by looking at the screenshots of your code.  In the first screenshot you define a class: `public class SendMail : IHttpHandler`.  In the last screenshot you define another class: `public class SendMail`.  Though I just noticed that the method *is* `static`, so I need to update that part of my answer...

Comment: I now have 'App_code\Mail.cs' in it ' public class MailClass' and 'public static bool SendEmail', from the handler I call  it like that: ' bool mailSent =MyNameSpace.MailClass.SendEmail(firstName, lastName.." and it shows an error saying "ambiguous reference: MyNameSpace.Mailclass X2"

Comment: @slash1z: Do you have more than one class called `MailClass` in the namespace `MyNameSpace`?  The compiler seems to think so.

Comment: no. I have just searched for it('ctrl-shift-f') just to be sure + rebuild the solution.

Comment: you have an idea for that?

Comment: I have now saw another thing that may help to solve it. In the ashx file if I hover the 'public class SendMail(hover the SendMail)'
a message appear saying "Namespace does Not correspond to file location, should be NameSpace.Handlers"

Comment: don't know why but I changes the folder name from `App_Code` to `AppCode` and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the namespace (let it be npsMail) of the sendMail class file. Then refer the sendMail class in the ashx file like `npsMail.sendMail`.